# Проблемы с отладкой

Tags: c#

При отладке при последовательном нажатии F10 процесс доходит до **comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 1;** а дальше идет не на **textBox1.Text = "345";**, а на **mas = new double[s];** в другом классе(второй рисунок). И выдается ошибка представленная на втором рисунке. **int s** равно отрицательному значению, хотя этот метод вызывается дальше в программе и значение **s** никак не должно получаться отрицательным.
В чем проблема?

[image]
[image]

Связь класса "Сигнал" с формой:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
...
if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                     Сигнал SIN = Форм_Син.G_sin(F, n_pd, F_DISCR);
                     userControl11.Length = SIN.size;
                     for (int i = 0; i < SIN.size; i++)
                     {
                        userControl11.x[i] = i / F_DISCR;
                        userControl11.y[i] = SIN[i];
                     }
                }
                else
                {
                     Сигнал LCHM = Форм_ЛЧМ.G_LHCM(F, F_DISCR, basa, n_pd);
                    userControl11.Length = LCHM.size;
                     for (int i = 0; i < LCHM.size; i++)
                    {
                             userControl11.x[i] = i / F_DISCR;
                             userControl11.y[i] = LCHM[i];
                    }
                 }
                }
            }
        }
```

Вторая связь класса "Сигнал" с формой:

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            Сигнал SIN = Форм_Син.G_sin(F, n_pd, F_DISCR);
            userControl11.Length = SIN.size;
            for (int i = 0; i < SIN.size; i++)
            {
               userControl11.x[i] = i / F_DISCR;
               userControl11.y[i] = SIN[i];
           }
          userControl11.P_ka();
       }
        if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            Сигнал LCHM = Форм_ЛЧМ.G_LHCM(F, F_DISCR, basa, n_pd);
            userControl11.Length = LCHM.size;
            for (int i = 0; i < LCHM.size; i++)
           {
                userControl11.x[i] = i / F_DISCR;
               userControl11.y[i] = LCHM[i];
           }
           userControl11.P_ka();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, как связан класс "Сигнал" с формой. У вас, наверное, есть обработчик события изменение выделенного индекса в ComboBox3. Когда вы программно меняете индекс выделенного элемента, событие также вызывается и обрабатывается, попробуйте пройтись с кнопкой F11, вместо F10, что убедиться в этом.

Comment: добавил код связи класса "Сигнал" с формой (написал в поле вопроса).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все правильно, вы писали, что этот метод вызывается дальше в программе, что не верно. Обработчик события вызывается сразу после того как вы поменяли выделенный индекс. А это значит, что после каждого

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex=0;
ComboBox2.SelectedIndex=0;
ComboBox3.SelectedIndex=1;
```

Вызывается свой обработчик. А это значит, что F, F_DISCR, basa, n_pd еще не проиницилизировались, то есть равны нулю по умолчанию. Вам проще всего будет перенести этот блок

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex=0;
ComboBox2.SelectedIndex=0;
ComboBox3.SelectedIndex=1;
```

в конец метода Form1_Load.